# Как определить количество символов до и после точки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip

Задача заключается в том, что нужно определить кол-во знаков до и после точки у ip, грубо говоря проверка правильности ввода ip адреса.

Например, пользователь вводит:

192.168.0.0 - тут всё ок и система пропускает т.е. True

192.168.1234.0 - вот тут уже система должна заругаться и не пропустить т.е. False, надеюсь все понимают почему ))

Вот думаю как бы это всё по компактней оформить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть модуль в стандартном наборе для расбора ip адресов

```
import ipaddress

ipaddress.ip_address("192.168.0.0")
IPv4Address('192.168.0.0')

ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.1234.0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ipaddress.py", line 54, in ip_address
    raise ValueError('%r does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address' %
ValueError: '192.168.1234.0' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
```

Через try/except можно делать проверки

Или так:

```
for i in map(int, "192.168.1234.0".split('.')):
    if i > 255 or i<0: raise ValueError('bad ip address')
```

Но например `127.1` или `192.168.1895` являются нормальными ip адресами и проверка на количество цифр не корректна в принципе.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказанную библиотеку )

Answer (score 1):

еще так:

```
ip = '192.168.0.0'

all(-1<int(i)<256 for i in ip.split('.'))  # True
```

**UPD**

про использование цепочек операторов сравнения в Python - [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons).

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily; for example, x < y <= z is
> equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once
> (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be
> false).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: двойное неравенство не работает в питоне

Comment: @eri, почему же? [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

Comment: хм.............был неправ